# Watch on actual size of element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm tring to create a directive that will watch on size on the other div element.

I have this code:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var win = angular.element($('#id'));
      win.bind('resize', function(e) {
        alert(win.height());
      });
    }
```

Element #id have width =100% and height = 100%. And when I resize my window did't happening.
So, what can I do to get actual win.height?

Answer (score 0):

```
win.bind('resize', function(event) {
    var height;

    height = event.currentTarget.clientHeight // with padding
    // or .offsetHeight (contains the height with the padding, scroll bar, and the border)

    alert(height);
});
```